# Adding animation to web page

Tags: html, css, svg

I am new to animations, i am creating a compass for which i need to create animating page as mentioned in following link. i don't know from where i get start. [Here is the link](https://qiblafinder.withgoogle.com/intl/en/desktop)
Any help will be very appreciated.
my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("div").animate({
      left: '250px'
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<body>

  <button>Start</button>


  <div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>
```

Comment: I think the only problem here is that you forgot to include JScript. Try adding this to the `<head>` section of your HTML: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: i just copied the selected script, in my home page animation is applying but i want to add custom animation like rotating image and adding zoom-in and zoom-out too, i gave example link in my question